# Pass a string to method CREATE RECORD in 4D

Tags: 4d-database

Can i pass a string variable to the 4D CREATE RECORD method ? or any other method i just need to set the name table as a variable.
I already tried to pass a string variable but as the method only accepts table object i can't find any way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a pointer. Anywhere 4D expects a table you can use a dereferenced pointer to a table.

You can get a pointer to a table in a few ways:

```
C_Pointer($pTable)
$pTable:=Table(4) // where 4 is the table number; command returns a pointer to the table
// -OR-
$pTable:=->[SomeTable] // directly setting a pointer to the table

CREATE RECORD($pTable->) // dereferenced pointer as parameter
// do some work here, setting field values
SAVE RECORD($pTable->)
```

Depending on how you are choosing the variable table name you may need some code to tie the text to the table or table number. A method that took the text and set a pointer to the table would do the trick.

**Update:**
Incorporating what @TomB suggested (I wasn't aware of that command), I would do something like this (though in real code I'd create a method that returned a pointer to the table rather than running Create Record in the If statement). Where $tSomeTableName is the string variable you are working with.

```
ARRAY TEXT($atTableNames;0)
ARRAY LONGINT($aLTableNumbers;0)
GET TABLE TITLES($atTableNames;$aLTableNumbers)

C_LONGINT($LFind)
$LFind:=Find in array($atTableNames;$tSomeTableName)

C_POINTER($pTable)
If ($LFind>0)
    $pTable:=Table($aLTableNumbers{$LFind})

    CREATE RECORD($pTable->)
      // do some work
    SAVE RECORD($pTable->)

Else 
    ALERT("Table name "+$tSomeTableName+" not recognized.")
End if
```

I prefer this to Execute Formula because it handles cases where the table name in the text variable is not a valid table name in the database.

Comment: Still not working ! what i do is i get a json object from a post http method and i put the name of the table i wanna use in a string variable so that variable is supposed to be the table i wanna use in 4D methods like CREATE RECORD

Comment: Take a look at @TomB's code. It should give you what you need to convert the text string to a pointer to the table.

Comment: It worked for me i had to do EXECUTE FORMULA("$ptr:=->["+name+"]") then put the pointer in the method thank you !

Comment: I'm glad it is working for you, but take a look at my updated example. Using EXECUTE FORMULA could lead to problems if the table name in the variable isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the table by name, you have to look it up first, as there is no way to call it up by name. Therefore to access the table named "myTableName":

```
$vT_tablename:="myTableName"
GET TABLE TITLES(aT_TableTitles;aL_TableNums)
$vL_MyTable_idx:=find in array(aT_TableTitles;$vT_tablename)
$vL_MyTable_Num:=aL_TableNums{$vL_MyTable_idx}
$vP_MyTable:=table($vL_MyTable_Num)
CREATE RECORD(vP_MyTable->)
```

...